# Bandwith USRP2

Tags: gnuradio

What is the maximum bandwith I can handle with an USRP2?

Answer (score 3):

USRP2 A/D samples at 100MS/s I & Q is decimated to 25MS/s complex.  We use 16-bit I & Q.
That works out to ~800Mbit/s on the gigabit ethernet,  which the USRP2
can sustain, no problem.